# Free ClamAV alternative working with Amavis on Linux ARMHF

Tags: linux, antivirus, arm, email-server

[ClamAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClamAV) is a virus scanner engine which a.o. works together with [Amavis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amavis) to check incoming mail for viruses. Unfortunately, it has two disadvantages: high resource consumption, and [not the best detection rate](https://threatcenter.crdf.fr/?Stats) (euphemism: in the linked results, it ranks at the end of the lists – [same here](http://blog.dynamoo.com/2013/10/an-informal-anti-virus-comparison.html)). So I want to replace it with a better alternative.

#### Requirements

- works on Linux ARMHF
- lightweight
- good detection rate (and low rate of "false positives")
- integrates with `amavisd-new`
- not too tricky to install (preferred: `.deb` for Debian Wheezy and up, best via repository)
- free (open-source preferred)

The environment is non-commercial ("ORG"). The virus scanner is just intended as a "convenience" for those few "mail clients" running on a Windows system – which somehow doesn't justify a solution eating about a third of all available RAM on the mail server while not offering real good protection.

---

2 years later, and still no answer here. Neither did I find something elsewhere, and meanwhile ClamAV is eating almost half of the RAM, getting killed by the OOM multiple times a day.

For those of you not having the ARM restriction, find some solutions at [Alternative to clamav that works with amavisd-new](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/40480/185). One of the solutions offered there (Sophos) would suit me fine if it were available on ARMHF …

Comment: Seems what I'm after does not exist: no answers, not even comments, within the 3 years I've posted it. As ClamAV meanwhile needs more RAM than my little box can provide, I've nuked it altogether. Got no Windows machines anyway. Still, if something came up, I'd probably take a look …

Answer (score 0):

Look into the commented parameters in the amavis-new config you'll find many other options like clamav (nearly preconfigured). Many of them like KasperSky have stopped providing support but there are still some options. Every antivirus have it's own way of performing so as far as performance is considered you'll have to try them one by one, you can write bash/python script which can simulate the good and bad email sending. Also there are some forks of clamav like Malscan which can be used but as far as I know they require more resources than clamav itself. I'll be glad if you keep me in loop.

Comment: I've had a look into the alternatives listed there back then, but none of them fit unfortunately. Thanks nevertheless!

Comment: @Izzy Did you tried to modify LMD and use it.

Comment: As I've no idea what you mean by LMD, probably not. And as the comment on my question shows, I already gave up 5 years ago. So while a solution with lower resource requirements is still interesting, I won't have the time for experiments, sorry.